# Microsoft Delve / Graph in local network area

Tags: sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, delve

Is it possible to run Microsoft Delve with Graph in a local network (intranet) with a local MS Sharepoint Server? Or is Graph/Delve only with Office 365 available?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph supports Office 365 for work and school accounts as well as personal accounts through outlook.com.

There are hybrid deployment scenarios in preview that require Exchange 2016. For more information, you can check the documentation on [Hybrid deployments in preview](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support).